# CSS Sprite Repeating Whole Sprite

Tags: css, css-sprites

this maybe a silly question but if someone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

I have a sprite consisting of 3 different images stacked vertically but I'm trying to get the middle one (Height of 1px and 194 width) to repeat and just that 1px line although when I call it it just repeats the whole thing, the title and :after works fine however but its just the one part that's being a pain.

```
<style>
.menu {
width: 194px;
background: url('menu.png') 0 -21px
}
.menu .title {
background: url('menu.png') 0 0;
width: 194px;
}
.menu:after {
display: block;
content: "";
background: url('menu.png') 0 -22px;
width: 194px;
height: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="menu">
<div class="title">[Title]</div>
This is some text here to test the element.
</div>
```

Menu image:

[image: menu image]

(If it helps the size of the map is as follows: top->194x21, middle->194x1 & bottom->194x10)

Actual result and aim:

[image]

I'm learning sprite maps and its just so confusing at times so any help is appreciated and thanks in advance for any help people can provide.

Comment: maybe you add height:1px to .menu class?

Comment: @cyan I've tried that prior to posting but it just limits the div's height to 1px, ideally just need to find a way to repeat that one specific pixel line without repeating the rest but honestly have not a clue how to do that and don't wish to include another image just to achieve that result unless I really have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't repeat part of an image, you can only repeat the full height (or full width, or both).

Place the three images side by side, so that you get a sprite image that is 582x21, and make the middle image fill the height of the sprite image.

Then you can repeat the middle part, as it repeats the full height of the sprite image:

```
.menu {
  width: 194px;
  background: url('menu.png') -194px 0;
}
.menu .title {
  background: url('menu.png') 0 0;
  width: 194px;
}
.menu:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background: url('menu.png') -388px 0;
  width: 194px;
  height: 10px;
}
```